# remove/add element href attribute by its unique path

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I have a tag that looks like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="Edit/44"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>...</a>
```

I want to remove a later re-add the `href` attribute to the element with this specific path(`"Edit/44"`), but it's its only unique identifier. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element to start with using an [attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-representation) (`[href="Edit/44"]` in this case) with `querySelector`:

```
const element = document.querySelector(`[href="Edit/44"]`);
```

Then you might move it to  a `data-*` attribute before clearing it:

```
element.setAttribute("data-href", element.href);
element.removeAttribute("href");
```

You can either keep a reference to `element` or find it later the same way, but with a different attribute name, then put it back:

```
const element = document.querySelector(`[data-href="Edit/44"]`);
element.setAttribute("href", element.getAttribute("data-href"));
element.removeAttribute("data-href");
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, [it works fine in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anastaciu/qfg64Lso/2/), but oddly enough, in my page the element is null, I should be missing something, for sure.

Comment: I think the problem was I was doing it in a document ready function, but since the data loanding is asyncronous, it was not loading in time.

Comment: @anastaciu - Yes, you'd have to wait until the element had been put in the DOM by whatever was loading it. Hopefully there's some event associated with that you can hook into. If not, worst case, you could use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).